# Level 1 C# / SQL Server Developer Test

Tags: c#, sql-server

We're looking to hire a Level 1 C#/SQL Server developer. In our company, a Level 1 developer would have 3-18 months of development experience. When we hire developers, we typically have them create an application based on requirements we give them. They are free to do this at home, within a reasonable amount of time.

We've typically hired Level 3 developers (> 10 years experience) in the past. This will be the first Level 1 we have hired.

I'm looking for help on what sort of requirements/project definition I could come up with to fairly test a Level 1 candidate. Generally speaking, I want this to include creating a database with perhaps a handful of tables, and then creating a WinForms application to read and write to that database. I want to test their skills in designing a database and their skills in creating a C# application to interact with that database.

I want to make it a challenge for a Level 1, but not too easy or hard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may learn more about a candidate by leaving the problem open-ended. Tell them to create a solution to a problem of their choice that includes at least:

- A database with `n` tables
- A UI with `m` forms

You'll learn about their interests, how they handle vague requirements, and their problem solving instincts. This is usually more valuable than their ability to follow a rigid spec since specs are notorious for changing.

Check their communication skills by having them explain their choices. If you want to be thorough, have them submit a short written explanation with their solution.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I intend to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ideas that you could use:

- Travel Booking System
- Simple Bank Transfers
- Pet Shop
- Staff Directory
- Help desk Ticketing system

These are just a few things off the top of my head.  What I would suggest is choosing a subject that the candidate is familiar with.

By this I mean, if they are interested in a certain sport etc then make the example based around something they know rather than something obscure that they don't know anything about.

This is a test of their ability to code and create database schemas - you don't want them to be concerned about whether they have the scenario correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about one of the following:

1. A simple event planner? say football fixtures or something..
2. Database to manage a blog (but i guess they would
   write a small website for that)
3. Bug Tracker

Answer (score 0):

- You could give him an incomplete database, let him design three or more tables, see if he follows the pattern.
- Then, you could give him some sort of integration to do. Like, integrating an Access or plain text file with SQL Server, through a Console Application.
- Lastly, you could put some proposital error in this integration, see how he would interact with it, how he would solve it. It could be an extra separator, something like that.

I guess this way, you would test his ability to develop, and his logic to solve problems.